# We need a name for our chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

So we have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/christianity). Other sites have cool names for their chat rooms. Isn't it time we named ours?

Please add your suggestions below: one suggestion per answer. Then the mods can make a decision based on the votes.

If you don't want to name the chat room, please vote this question down. And if you do, vote it up!

**Please also add a line of explanation for your suggestion!**

**Update:** we're now up to *sixteen* answers! I suggest we wait 48 more hours and then just pick the highest voted answer.

Comment: I'm thinking something incorporating "Berea" (since the Bereans were big on testing what the pastor preached against Scripture and studying the Bible), but i'm not sure exactly what...

Comment: @DoubtingThomas: How about [Berean Babel](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1102/30)?

Comment: BTW: 16 answers = 15 visible + 1 deleted

Comment: How many votes or how large a margin until we take it and run with it (at least until a new idea comes along)?

Comment: @Caleb: I suggest we just chose the highest. We can always review it and change it. FWIW, [we selected a name at sci-fi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/751/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom) but this [wasn't universally popular](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/do-we-like-the-name-of-our-chatroom). Sometimes, we've just got to decide and go for it - we'll never please everyone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[The Upper Room](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%201:13&version=NIV1984)**

Explanation: this is the famous room where the church started with the [arrival of The Holy Spirit](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202&version=KJV). I was looking for a place where Christians were together, this seemed a well known candidate.

Comment: That evokes the ideas of (a) worship, and (b) hiding from a dangerous world. I'm not sure that either is appropriate. But meh, close enough.

Comment: @TRiG: I would respond, but I'm currently stuck with my tambourine in a bunker...

Comment: We have a Peter, a Jon (close enough), a Doubting Thomas, so we are well on our way to filling the table.  But, it makes me uncomfortable for some reason.  (Maybe because I just compared myself with St. John.)

Comment: This sounds kind of exclusive. Considering the fact that [this is not a Christian site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/193/30) I would suggest we find something that iconifies the interaction between Christian and non Christian perspectives that happens around here.

Comment: @Caleb that's a good point. But while apologetics is encouraged in the Bible, we don't really see it going on a lot - it's mostly just preaching. hm.

Comment: @DoubtingThomas: I'm all for preaching. Now, where were we?

Comment: @Caleb I would think the sorts of discussion we'd have in chat would not be preaching (proclamation) but apologetics (discussion and debate)

Comment: @Caleb: Yeah.  That's kinda what troubled me too.

Comment: I upvoted this, but I think it's a little much to live up to!

Comment: @Caleb on the other hand, several other chat rooms have "exclusive" names that nominally restrict its users to experts,  but amateurs or non-experts are still welcome. I think that could be the case here - most of us in the room would be Christians or at least semi-experts on it, while the rest are still 100% welcome to converse and debate. Still, there's room for a better name..

Comment: @DoubtingThomas agreed. It could be more esoteric, it could be "The Cenacle"

Comment: I have reversed my position on this because, while it seems less than ideal to me, there are plenty of suggestions showing up that I like a lot less and no momentum seems to be behind the ones I really like.

Comment: This is the current winner, [see details in chat here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4434798#4434798).

Comment: @Caleb: "The best is the enemy of the good."--Voltaire  (I concur with you.)

Answer (score 6):

**Berean Babel***

* I stole this idea from [Doubting Thomas](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/we-need-a-name-for-our-chat-room#comment2340_1092)

Comment: interesting <!--char limit-->

Comment: @DoubtingThomas: I did actually get above the char limit the first time, and the system auto-converted my answer to a comment on the grounds that it was "trivial". I've never seen that feature before. I re-created it with enough jabber to convince it this wasn't a trivial suggestion.

Comment: whoa. and whatever else I need for char limit again.

Comment: This is clever but I think it will make most people scratch their heads.

Comment: @JustinY: The fallout of that mixup at the tower has had people scratching their heads over the meaning of words for thousands of years. Your point being?

Answer (score 3):

**Hall of Tyrannus 2.0***

<sub>* Tyrannus is of course a reference to [Acts 19:9](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Acts%2019:9/), not [the hulk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannus_%28comics%29). The 2.0 is a nod to SE and most of our constituency.</sub>

Comment: If ever an answer required further explanation, [this is it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannus_(comics))... :)

Comment: @Wikis: And I still don't get it.

Comment: @Wikis What in the name of South American giraffes? I was thinking more along the lines of [Acts 19:9](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Acts%2019%3A9/).

Comment: **Not** about the Hulk?! Gah, there goes my vote... ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Three Taverns](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4259285#4259285).

Comment: This is the best of the bunch so far.

Answer (score 2):

Coffee Hour.

After every church service, Episcopalians (and many others) have a coffee hour where we just kinda shoot the breeze. Its the closest we actually come to "fellowship"

Comment: Perhaps, "coffee *time*". I'm nitpicking, but specifying a duration might be overly ambitious...

Comment: The [third sacrament](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5247/what-are-the-protestant-arguments-against-a-sacramental-economy#comment14018_5247) doesn't work, sadly.  I think we ought not to exclude Mormon participation in any case.

Comment: I wish our church did this. We do have fellowship meals (best. time. ever.), but i wish we did them every sunday. +1, btw. good idea.

Answer (score 2):

**[Open Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Jesus#Table_fellowship)** or *Table Fellowship*.

Comment: This to include non-Christians and all denominations.

Answer (score 1):

#### So much straw

I always fancied writing an app by this name to scour the internet and find all the good arguments. But I think it would be a good name for what goes on in the chat room :) and the phrase has at least both Catholic and Protestant connotations (in my mind at least). Although, to be sure, it doesn't indicate a "room".

Comment: Now that I know the [origin](http://chaplainlem.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/so-much-straw/) of the quote, I like it a lot.  I'd rank it just under [Three Taverns](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1096/914).

Answer (score 1):

**[Nose Meets Toes](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2012:12-31&version=NIV1984)**

Comment: *This is the most ridiculous post I have ever made bar none.*

Answer (score 1):

**[The Church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesia_%28church%29)**

After all, the church is the people, not the building, right?

Answer (score 0):

[**The Temple Court**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%202:46&version=NIV)

(This being where Jesus sat as a teenager and debated the theology buffs of the temple)

Answer (score 0):

### **[The Arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah%27s_Ark)**

We are the salt of this world, and we are the ones who stay awake and pray for the coming of the lord. In a sense, we are in an arc. Arc represents us, who stays awake, and soon to be the ones going to the paradise.

Answer (score 0):

**The Chapel**

A common name for Christian assemblies, I think it works in many strands of Christianty.

Answer (score -1):

"The Body"

A reference to 1 Corinthians 12. (And slightly less ridiculuous "Noses Meet Toeses" which is actually going in a good direction)

Answer (score -1):

The Fellowship

Of course, you'll probably get lots of Lord of the Rings fans here, but meh...

Comment: Sounds like we're starting a cult... ;)

Answer (score -2):

[Debates About Words](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4259368#4259368)

Comment: It's a chat room, so much more than a place for debating.